Why reversible potential of water oxidation is reported as 1.23 V and not -1.23V?
The standard Gibbs free energy of formation for water is -237 kJ/mol, the $\Delta G^\circ$ for the opposite reaction (water splitting) is 237 kJ/mol (non-spontaneous).  If we use this value to calculate the reversible potential for water splitting we get -1.23 V. However the reversible potential is always displayed as 1.23 V, which would indicate the reaction is spontaneous, and is not. Can someone please help me to clarify this?
$$
\Delta G^\circ_{\text{f,liq}} = 237 kJ/mol \\
E^\circ_{\text{rev}} = -\frac{\Delta G^\circ}{nF} = -1.23 V
$$

About potentials and electrochemistry, there was always confusion. Like for half reaction redox potential ( sign depending on reaction direction ) or electrode (physical) potential (sign direction independent). If potential for the whole cell is considered, it needs voltage for reversible electrolysis 1.23 V, and a cell provides reversibly in a galvanic mode 1.23 V as well.
